# How to explicitly choose elements from a list

Tags: python, list, code-cleanup

```
my_list = ["zero", "wow", "peach", 3, 4, "nice", "pickle"]
```

I want to print "wow", "nice", "peach"

So:

```
my_list[1]
my_list[5]
my_list[2]
```

How can I do this in one line, or at-least quicker than the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to return a list of values:

```py
[my_list[i] for i in [1, 5, 2]]
```

Or to print one by one:

```py
for i in [1, 5, 2]:
    print(my_list[i])
```

or as a 1-liner using the argument unpacking (`*`) operator to "flatten" a generator:

```py
print(*(my_list[i] for i in [1, 5, 2]), sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `operator.itemgetter`

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> my_list = ["zero", "wow", "peach", 3, 4, "nice", "pickle"]
>>> itemgetter(1, 5, 2)(my_list)
('wow', 'nice', 'peach')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
print(*map(lambda x: my_list[x], [1, 5, 2]))
```

Output:

```
 wow nice peach
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use list comprehension

```
>>> [my_list[x] for x in [1, 5, 2]]
['wow', 'nice', 'peach']
```

or even

```
>>> [print(my_list[x]) for x in [1, 5, 2]]
wow
nice
peach
```

Comment: Calling `print` inside a list comprehension is bad form. List comprehensions shouldn't have side effects. Just use a regular `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone like a simple way without any library of complex looking syntax this might be a solution!

To make code look clean the best way is to have a function for it it makes it both more clean and also has more features.

**Code :**

```
def printList(list, *index, all=False):
    if all:
        for item in list:
            print(item)
    else:
        for i in index:
            print(list[i])

my_list = ["zero", "wow", "peach", 3, 4, "nice", "pickle"]

printList(my_list, 1, 5, 2) # To print some elements
print("---------------------------")
printList(my_list, all=True)
```

**Output :**

```
wow
nice
peach
---------------------------
zero
wow
peach
3
4
nice
pickle
```